# How can a trimmed avi file be three times larger than the original

Tags: video-editing, avi, video-conversion, trim

I opened up a [avi file in virtualdub](http://www.virtualdub.org/download.html) and trimmed the clip and clicked "Save as avi" and it saved the trimmed clip but it was 3 times the size of the original clip. How can that be?

Comment: You most likely went from a compressed AVI to an Uncompressed AVI as stated by szeli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can be due to the codecs involved. different codecs offer different compression rates and quality. when you 'Save as avi' did you check which codec was it configured to use?